# Regularity of $K[X,Y]/(X^p + Y^p - a)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, regular-rings

In his paper ["The concept of a simple point of an abstract algebraic variety"](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1947-062-01/S0002-9947-1947-0021694-1/S0002-9947-1947-0021694-1.pdf) Oscar Zariski provides in Example 1 a regular but not smooth variety over a field $K$.

In his example $K$ is a non-perfect field of characteristic $p$ and
$$X = \operatorname{Spec} K[X,Y]/(X^p + Y^p - a),$$
where $a$ is an element of $K$ which is not a $p$-th power.

I see that $X$ is not smooth since the Jacobian matrix is $(0)$ and therefore not of maximal rank.
I also know that the example would not work if $K$ was perfect.

But I have problems proving the regularity of $X$. Zariski mentions that the curve is (obviously?) normal, but I don't see why and in particular I don't know where the non-perfectness of $K$ has to be used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the change of variables $(X,Y) \mapsto (X,X+Y)$, we have that $X$ is isomorphic to $K[X,Y]/(X^{p}-a)$. Setting $L := K[X]/(X^{p}-a)$, which is a purely inseparable field extension of $K$, we have $K[X,Y]/(X^{p}-a) \simeq L[Y]$, which is a regular ring but is not smooth over $K$.

Comment: So $L/K$ is already not smooth, since it is purely inseparable?

Comment: Yes. In general, if $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$ are morphisms of schemes such that $gf$ is smooth and $f$ is surjective and smooth, then $g$ is smooth (see e.g. [05B5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05B5)).